# convert map to list for terraform aws_autoscaling_group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following map of subnet ids as a variable to be used in a Terraform `aws_autoscaling_group` resource:

```
subnet_ids = {
  "us-east-1" = "subnet-123abc,subnet-456def,subnet-789ghi"
  "us-west-2" = "subnet-1a2b3c,subnet-4c5d6e,subnet-7g8h9i"
}
```

and variable as

```
variable subnet_ids {
  description = "subnet ids"
  type        = "map"
}
```

but this not working as Terraform is complaining that it needs a list but is seeing a map.

This worked by just setting up one region temporarily:

```
subnet_ids = ["subnet-123abc", "subnet-456def", "subnet-789ghi"]
```

and variable as:

```
variable subnet_ids {
  description = "subnet ids"
  type        = "list"
}
```

and passed as `vpc_zone_identifier  = "${var.subnet_ids}"`

So pretty much want a way to be able to use the map and be able to pass in lists based on the region picked

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `lookup` command and a variable to represent your `region` to choose a value from your `map`:

```
variable region {
   description = "aws region"
   default = "us-east-1"
}

...

vpc_zone_identifier = ["${lookup(var.subnet_ids, var.region)}"]
```

[See the documentation for more examples.](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/variables.html#maps)

Comment: does not work still
`vpc_zone_identifier: should be a list`
`variable subnet_ids should be type list, got map`

Comment: i tried that before posting this question and did not work and just tried your answer again..same error

Comment: Try using square brackets like this: `vpc_zone_identifier = ["${lookup(var.subnet_ids, var.region)}"]` does that work?

Comment: you know why terraform keeps using default VPC instead of the VPC with he subnets i passed? no option to specify the VPC id itself

Comment: tried to apply same thing to security_groups for launch configuration and am running into this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3942#issuecomment-173425434 stuck now..not sure how to pass in the security groups from map

Comment: Not too sure - want to ask a new question for more help?

Comment: it is same exact thing as subnet but for security groups..i will if that is what is necessary

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing issues with `security groups` for autoscaling group resource in terraform, this is how you pass map to list

this is what worked

```
security_groups = ["${split(",",lookup(var.security_groups, var.aws_region))}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
variable region {
   description = "aws region"
   default = "us-east-1"
}

...

vpc_zone_identifier = ["${var.subnet_ids["${var.region}"]}"]
```